# Packagist is not picking up my new release from GitHub

Tags: php, github, composer-php, packagist

I released a new version of my composer package on GitHub, however it is not updating on Packagist, not even when I manually click 'Update' on the package page. The weird thing is that it does show the latest version of the README file. Also, the last updated time is shown correctly on Packagist.

It is about this package:
https://packagist.org/packages/jeroennoten/laravel-adminlte
https://github.com/JeroenNoten/Laravel-AdminLTE

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Note that your master branch (`dev-master`) is indeed up-to-date on Packagist (commit `50f874c` on both Packagist and GitHub).

**However**, your latest Git tag `v.1.2.1` is incorrectly named. To quote the [Packagist documentation](https://packagist.org/about):

> Tag/version names should match 'X.Y.Z', or 'vX.Y.Z', with an optional suffix for RC, beta, alpha or patch versions. Here are a few examples of valid tag names:
>
> ```
> 1.0.0
> v1.0.0
> 1.10.5-RC1
> v4.4.4beta2
> v2.0.0-alpha
> v2.0.4-p1
> ```

For a version *1.2.1*, valid Git tag names would be either `1.2.1` or `v1.2.1`.