# Packagist does not take tags/releases that i push

Tags: github, composer-php, packagist

here is my pushed tags[image]

here is my packagist

[image]

does anyone know how to resolve this?

Comment: What do you want to resolve?

Comment: the issues is packagist does not detect tags from bitbucket. Any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some webhooks to be added to your repository server, see https://packagist.org/about#how-to-update-packages for them - this will update the list of package versions immediately on pushing or tagging. Otherwise, updates are only performed once a week

Comment: Did you create a new tag after adding the hooks?

Comment: Hmmm , i find it odd because yesterday i tried create new tag after i added the webhooks , but not working , but today i create new tag and it's suddenly working

Comment: Nico , why when i tag for example 'v.1.0.1-dev' ,packagist does not take this tag ?
but when i tag for example 'v.1.0.1' , packagist does take it .
Do you know why?

Comment: Sorry, no, I don't have a clue

Comment: v.1.0.1-dev is not a valid tag name. You shouldn't have a v., it should be v1.0.1. Potentially also -dev is not a valid suffix. Answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36142984/packagist-is-not-picking-up-my-new-release-from-github